# Python API Call: KeyError

Tags: python, json, rest, keyerror

I'm working with a python [script](https://github.com/UAlbanyArchives/describingWebArchives/blob/master/describingWebArchives.py) that performs a web API call to one system (ArchivesSpace), extracts JSON data from it, uses that data to search another system via its API (Archive-It), then extracts the result before pushing it into the original system. When I run the script, it seems to perform the initial API call just fine, but hangs either when performing the second or when hitting line 730 in [aspace.py](https://github.com/UAlbanyArchives/archives_tools/blob/master/build/lib/archives_tools/aspace.py#L730) (I'm not sure which). I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".\describingWebArchives.py", line 81, in <module>
for result in AS.withSubject(session, repo, aitSubject, aitSource, aspaceLogin):
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\archives_tools\aspace.py", line 730, in withSubject
if result["source_enum_s"][0].lower() == str(source).lower():
KeyError: 'source_enum_s'
```

I think that the KeyError indicates that `source_enum_s` is an unrecognized library term, but that's as far as I've gotten. I'd really appreciate some help in either fixing or understanding this!

Comment: Well, yeah it means that `result` does not have a key by the name `source_enum_s` in this line `if result["source_enum_s"][0].lower() == str(source).lower()`. You can try to `print(result)` to find out what it contains.

Comment: Is it possible that the API call is failing, and that's why there's no "source_enum_s" to reference?

Comment: Yeah, that's possible. If you are making a request to a server, you can check the status code to see if it is returning an error. Sorry I don't have the full picture of what you are trying to do. And how you are doing it.